# How to differentiate clients if we are using 1 number for multiple clients to send SMS to users using Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to integrate twilio API to my java code. I have come across a scenario, I have clients A and B. I have send them SMS using twilio and receive the reply back. I am not sure how do I differentiate between the two replies that I would get from the user to my single twilio number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can either work this out by recording which numbers client A has sent messages to and when you get responses from them assign them to client A and then the same for client B.

Or you could buy one more Twilio number and assign one to client A and the other to client B and split things out based on the incoming Twilio number.